# How to accumulate values entered by user?

Tags: vb.net

I am totally stuck on this assignment for class. I have a program that calculates sales taxes and percents.. but I need to have 3 accumulating text boxes; i.e When the user enters their subtotal, itll save to a variable and then the next time they enter somthing, it'll add it to that same variable and display it.
I have been at this for **hours** and have no luck and keep getting errors.

```
Dim numberOfInvoices As Integer
Dim totalOfInvoices As Decimal
Dim invoiceAverage As Decimal

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim subtotal As Decimal = CDec(txtEnterSubtotal.Text)
    Dim discountPercent As Decimal = 0.25D
    Dim discountAmount As Decimal = Math.Round(subtotal * discountPercent, 2)
    Dim invoiceTotal As Decimal = subtotal - discountAmount
    Dim accumSubtotal As Decimal = subtotal

    txtSubtotal.Text = FormatCurrency(subtotal)
    txtDiscountPercent.Text = FormatPercent(discountPercent, 1)
    txtDiscountAmount.Text = FormatCurrency(discountAmount)
    txtTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(invoiceTotal)

    numberOfInvoices += 1
    totalOfInvoices += invoiceTotal
    invoiceAverage = totalOfInvoices / numberOfInvoices

    Me.txtNumberOfInvoices.Text = numberOfInvoices.ToString
    Me.txtTotalOfInvoices.Text = FormatCurrency(totalOfInvoices)
    Me.txtInvoiceAverage.Text = FormatCurrency(invoiceAverage)


   '-------This is where i've been trying to accumulate values------'
   'I need to accumulate the subtotal everytime the user enters something
   'txtAccumSubtotal.text = 'the variable that adds evertime a new number is input into txtEnterSubtotal.text

    txtEnterSubtotal.Text = ""
    txtEnterSubtotal.Select()
    'This is a comment
End Sub
```

Hopefully I explained this right in the code. I really need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time they click, you are assigning the current SubTotal to AccumSubTotal.  Declare Accum Sub outside the Click event, then add the new SubTotal to it.

Give it a try...I'd show code, but you do wanna learn, no?  Hint:

```
AccumSubTotal += subtotal
```

or old school

```
AccumSubTotal = AccumSubTotal + subtotal
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Didn't even need that hint :)